# Sphero - Joystick does not work

Tags: sphero-api

The asset of Unity of  Sphero does not work.
The calibration button is OK, but Joystick there is no reaction.
I tried the scene UISAMPLESCENE and The prefab joystick
Someone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just pushed an update to the Unity plugin on github, give it a try, it should fix the issue.